# Venn Diagram Set Theory Question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So Given that Set A and B are disjoint, then A intersection C and B intersection C are also disjoint.

Now I'm having trouble figuring out how to exactly draw That A intersection C and B intersection C are also disjoint. Would I just draw Set C in the middle of Set A & B and then A intersects with B and Set C intersects with B?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you pretty much have it. The diagram would look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I assumed that's how it looked but wasn't completely sure.

Answer (score 1):

Any Venn diagram you draw will provide only an example of your claim being true. I'm not sure how much this would help to build intuition. The best way to get an intuitive grasp of this fact is probably to draw a Venn diagram with $A$ and $B$ disjoint, then try (in vain) to draw in a third set $C$ such that $A \cap C$ and $B \cap C$ intersect. A few seconds of trying to make such a diagram should make it clear why one cannot exist.

Without any visuals at all, it may help to realize that this fact follows from distributivity of set intersection: $(A \cap C) \cap (B \cap C) = (A \cap B) \cap C = \varnothing \cap C = \varnothing$.

Concrete examples also give great intuition. Take any two mutually exclusive properties to characterize the disjoint sets $A$ and $B$. Let's use *wet* and *dry*. Now, define a set $C$ with any other property, maybe *purple*. We know that nothing is *wet* and at the same time *dry*. It's also pretty clear that nothing is *wet and purple* and at the same time *dry and purple*.